# How can I retrieve specific data from ScriptDB database?

Tags: google-apps-script

As a learning exercise, I'm trying to query ScriptDb and return a person's name when my script has their email address. The function below returns "ScriptDbResult" instead of the correct name (which should be Patrick Farmer - see the list below the function). Can somebody please advise on what I'm doing wrong?

```
function getNameFromDb() {
var email = "patrickf@spambob.com";
var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
var result = db.query(
    {Names: {Emails: email}});
Logger.log(result);
}
```

This is what the Logger shows is in the database:

```
{
  "Emails": "lucaj@spambob.com",
  "Names": "Luca Jenkins"
}
{
  "Emails": "patrickf@spambob.com",
  "Names": "Patrick Farmer"
}
{
  "Emails": "elizabethj@trashymail.com",
  "Names": "Elizabeth Jennings"
}
{
  "Emails": "gabrielr@pookmail.com",
  "Names": "Gabriel Ryan"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. You indeed get back a ScriptDBResult object. You need to fecth results using the next method

```
while (result.hasNext()){
  var obj = result.next(); 
  Logger.log(obj.Names);
  Logger.log(obj.Emails);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for such a rapid response Srik. I got an error message to start with but when I changed my query from 'var result = db.query(
    {Names: {Emails: email}});' to 'var result = db.query(
    {Emails: email});' it worked a treat.